# Launching browser within CherryPy

Tags: python, browser, cherrypy

I have a html page displayed using...

```
cherrypy.quickstart(ShowHTML(htmlfile), config=configfile)
```

Once the page is loaded (eg. initiated via. the command 'python mypage.py'), I would like to automatically launch the browser to display the page (eg. via. http://localhost/8000).  Is there any way I can achieve this (eg. via. a hook within CherryPy), or do I have to call-up the browser manually (eg. by double-clicking an icon)?

TIA
Alan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either hook your webbrowser into the engine start/stop lifecycle:

```
def browse():
    webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:8080")
cherrypy.engine.subscribe('start', browse, priority=90)
```

Or, unpack quickstart:

```
from cherrypy import config, engine, tree

config.update(configfile)
tree.mount(ShowHTML(htmlfile), '/', configfile)
if hasattr(engine, "signal_handler"):
    engine.signal_handler.subscribe()
if hasattr(engine, "console_control_handler"):
    engine.console_control_handler.subscribe()

engine.start()
webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:8080")    
engine.block()
```

Comment: fumanchu - that's great!  Your cherrypy.engine.subscribe... solution works a treat.  Many thanks.